# Kendo-UI Grid in a Tab

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am looking into using Kendo UI Web on a new HTML5 Web app and the wireframes call for grids inside tabs.  I looked everywhere on Telerik's site, and the web, but I don't see any examples of this being done.  Is that not possible?  Or is there a better approach, like simply using the Tab control above the area where the Grid control would appear, giving it the appearance that the Grid is part of the Tab?

Answer (score 2):

There should be nothing stopping you from using a Kendo UI Grid within a Kendo UI TabStrip. Check out the [demo for the TabStrip](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/tabstrip/index.html) and the [demo for the Grid](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html). Hopefully that gets you on your way.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Still wondering why there is no demo of this happening though...all they show is straight text in the Tab demos.  I think it would better serve them, and the Kendo control suite, to show interaction between their controls :)

Answer (score 1):

The details template demo has a tabstrip within a grid and one of the tab is another grid, the second tab having a template.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate